# How to save something to Instapaper with TweetCaster

Tags: share-menu, tweetcaster, instapaper

I have TweetCaster Pro (thank you Amazon Daily App...) and it has a place for me to enter my Instapaper account in the Settings, but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to send something from TweetCaster to Instapaper.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one took me a while. Go into "Personalize TweetCaster" in settings and change "URL action" to "ask".